# Mapping a table with only foreign keys in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, foreign-keys, hibernate-mapping

I am new to hibernate and i want to map a table having only foreign keys using xml file.
I have 3 tables 
1.UserInfo(for user details with a primary key)
2.AuthorInfo(containing author details with a primary key)
3.AuthorFollow(to map which user is following which author).
The AuthorFollow table contains only 2 columns UserId and AuthorId both are having relationships(foreign keys) with the 1st 2 tables respectively.
I haven't given any index on these columns.

I have written below code in AuthorFollow.hbm.xml

But, its not working properly.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

```
    <composite-id>
        <key-many-to-one name="userId" column="user_id" class="com.pojo.hibernate.UserInfo" />
        <key-many-to-one name="authorId" column="author_id" class="com.pojo.hibernate.AuthorInfo" />
    </composite-id>

</class>
```

(i have used mysql.)

And, is the table structure proper?

Comment: You shouldn't map this table at all. There should be a many-to-many association between Author and User. And please, XML mapping was cool when we all used JDK 1.4, 8 years ago. Use annotations to map your entities.

Comment: thanks for the answer.& of course it worked.
but, i have another question.
If that mapping table contains a 3rd column then what should i do?

Comment: Then you should map it, and transform the ManyToMany into two OneToMany associations.